# Lock Idea record on field update

Tags: apex, locking, ideas

I need a way to lock an Idea and its comments from being editable. I have a time-based workflow already set up to change a custom field after 30 days. The custom field is called voting status with options of "Open" and "Locked". I'm thinking of two options:

Create a trigger to lock the record down after the field change similar to how it locks after an approval process is locked.

Or create a trigger that makes the record read-only after the field change.

Any ideas or examples on how to achieve this? I've been searching the API documentation and found the FOR UPDATE statement, but I haven't been able to implement anything.

Example so far:

Trigger IdeaRecordLock on Idea (after update, after insert) {
  for (Idea a : Trigger.New) {
    if (a.Voting_Status__c == 'Locked') {
    List lockemSockem = [SELECT Id FROM Idea WHERE Voting_Status__c = 'Locked' FOR UPDATE];
    }
    }
    }

Comment: Do you want the record lock as in an approval process lock/ do you want it read only and dont care about the lock

Comment: `FOR UPDATE` is intended to be used to lock records only during the context of the running process of a trigger or class. This prevents other users, triggers or classes from modifying those records during the running context/instance of that trigger or class. Its not intended for use as means of permanently locking the records that are returned.

Answer (score 1):

It has been possible to [lock records by Id in Apex since Winter16](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm#rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks) (late 2015).

If you're interested in not using apex for everything, I've also created [an Apex Plugin for Process Builder](https://github.com/mshanemc/processBuilderBlocks/blob/master/src/classes/PBBLock.cls) that can do this (doesn't help with Ideas because they're not in PB, but useful for other locking scenarios):

Answer (score 0):

Unless you write a validation rule and check for all the fields you want to keep locked using ISCHANGED(), you will have lock a record with apex. Not to mention the validation rule would unable to scale as you added new fields to the object.

You can submit a record for approval via apex and it will lock it. I've worked in a scenario where I had to use apex to lock and unlock a record. As long as you have an approval process setup on the object you want to lock you should be able to use the SF documentation below:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm

Comment: approval process cannot be created on Ideas, so the second part of the solution won't work.

Comment: Darn, I didn't know that. If you want to use the second option, you can write an approval process in all code. See the 3rd response by Sonam_SFDC:  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008syqIAA